# Return next not blank result based on a raw

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas

I have the following sheet using G-sheets:
[image]

I have the following formula in H2

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(E2:E="", F2:F, IF(G2:G="", E2:E, G2:G)))
```

I want Col H to return non-empty text in columns E,F,G, but the formula does not return text from Col G.
I wrote in Col I the result I want.
Hope you guys can help

Comment: Is there going to be a scenario where lets say there are comments in both `E` and `G` on a single row?!

Comment: @rockinfreakshow no it will only be data in one of the columns per raw, the formula works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You may try this in **Cell_H2**:*

```js
=byrow(E2:G,lambda(Σ,if(counta(Σ)=0,,+torow(Σ,1))))
```